# Python multithreading crawler for unknown size

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a list of pages to crawl using selenium

Let's say the website is example.com/1...N (up to unknown size)

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def crawl_example(page):
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver.get(f"example.com/{page}")
  # Do some processing
  result = "Fetched data"
  return result


N_THREAD = 10
MAX_SIZE = 100

with ThreadPoolExecutor(N_THREAD) as ex:
  futures = [ex.submit(crawl_example, page) for page in range(MAX_SIZE)]
```

Setting MAX_SIZE call unnecessary request after N, so I wanted to find a better solution.
I could only think of creating a global variable (is_done) or add another parameter to the function.

What would be the most pythonic approach to solve the above issue?

Comment: are you looking to adjust `MAX_SIZE` run time? like you get 404 from function `crawl_example` then you adjust max_size or exit the executor? is there a way you can find N before you start the executor?

Comment: Yes, I would like to adjust MAX_SIZE at run time. I cannot find N before crawling unless I do some binary search on MAX_SIZE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize a `last_page` variable to be infinity (preferably in a class variable)

And update and crawl with the following logic would be good enough

Since two threads can update `last_page` at the same time,

prevent higher `page` overwrite `last_page` updated by lower `page`

```py
from threading import Lock
last_page_lock = Lock()

def crawl_page(page):
  if page > last_page:
    continue
  if page_empty():
    with last_page_lock():
      last_page = min(last_page, page)
  ...
```